# package get installed under the include folder and not under site-packages

Tags: python, conda, diplib

I am trying to install a package (more specifically `diplib`) with `conda install -c conda-forge diplib` but for some reason nothing is added to `envs/env_name/lib/site-packages`. The command runs fine, no warnings/error at all. Everything looks normal but I am still getting `'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diplib'` error. However I can find a folder `diplib` under `envs/env_name/include` (actually it contains header files).

Does anyone know what has happened please? What is the include folder for? Are we supposed to import packages from it or something is wrong with the conda package and I need to remove (how?) the `diplid` that appeared under the `include` directory

This is in Ubuntu (in case it matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search brought me to [the Conda-Forge package called “diplib-feedstock”](https://github.com/conda-forge/diplib-feedstock). This is likely the source of the package you’re trying to install. From the docs of that repo:

> Installing `diplib` from the `conda-forge` channel can be achieved by adding `conda-forge` to your channels with:
>
> ```bash
> conda config --add channels conda-forge
> conda config --set channel_priority strict
> ```
>
> Once the `conda-forge` channel has been enabled, `diplib, diplib-python` can be installed with `conda`:
>
> ```bash
> conda install diplib diplib-python
> ```

It looks like the `diplib` package is the library (with include files as you found out), and `diplib-python` is the Python package.

---

The DIPlib project provides an official Python package through PyPI: `pip install diplib`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had totally missed `diplib-python`